# Adding new column with set of rules in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, partitioning

I have a somewhat-complex set of rules that I need to run against a table. The problem is as follows: I have a table that stores medical records and I need to identify the first site that a person goes to after their discharge date. The discharge date is the end_date with a location of 'initial' (this will be the first row for every group). The table is grouped by ID and sorted in the format shown below.

There are 3 rules: (1) within the group of ID, if any of the rows have a begin_date that matches the first rows end_date, return that location as the first site (if there are two rows that meet this condition, either are correct, the first instance is preferred). (2) if the first option does not exist, then if there is an instance that the patient had location 'Health', then return 'Health'. (3) else, if conditions 1 and 2 do not exist, then return 'Home'

table

```
ID    color  begin_date    end_date     location
1     red    2017-01-01    2017-01-07   initial
1     green  2017-01-05    2017-01-07   nursing
1     blue   2017-01-07    2017-01-15   rehab
1     red    2017-01-11    2017-01-22   Health
2     red    2017-02-22    2017-02-26   initial
2     green  2017-02-26    2017-02-28   nursing
2     blue   2017-02-26    2017-02-28   rehab
3     red    2017-03-11    2017-03-22   initial
4     red    2017-04-01    2017-04-07   initial
4     green  2017-04-05    2017-04-07   nursing
4     blue   2017-04-10    2017-04-15   Health
```

final result:

```
ID    first_site
1     rehab
2     nursing
3     home
4     Health
```

In sql-server 2008 my attempt: (side note: I considered adding a helper column which would be the end_date of the 'initial' location to each row so its easier to compare within a row. Not sure if this is necessary). I appreciate any guidance!

```
SELECT
ID,
OVER( PARTITION ID CASE WHEN end_date[0] = begin_date THEN location
                        WHEN location = 'Health' THEN 'Health'
                        ELSE 'Home' end) AS [first_site]
FROM table
```

In python, I was able to get this answer with:

```
def conditions(x):
    #compare each group first
    val = x.loc[x['begin_date'] == x['end_date'].iloc[0], 'location']
    #if at least one match (not return empty `Series` get first value)
    if not val.empty:
        return val.iloc[0]
    #if value is empty, check if value 'Health' exists within the group 
    elif (x['location']  == 'Health').any():
        return 'Health'
    else:
        return 'Home'

final = df.groupby('ID').apply(conditions).reset_index(name='first_site')
```

Comment: The data is grouped by ID only.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. You take about discharge date but there is nothing to indicate that. And how do you get "home" for ID 3? That value isn't in the sample data. You also have a challenge here. You refer to "first row" but by definition a table is an unordered set. The concept of first only applies when selecting data. You need to a more thorough job at explaining the rules here.

Comment: I'm  confused by your question..you say you have a function.  Where is it?

Comment: I addressed the concerns in the question stem. @SeanLange the table is sorted so that the first row is will be the 'initial' hospital visit. In regards to 'Home' for ID 3, the final condition (if the other two are not present) should return 'Home' as described in the question.

Comment: Remember that your table is not sorted. You see it that way but it is not an ordered set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a windowed function to rank the visits that start on the same day as the `initial` end and then a couple simple `join`s:

```
declare @t table(ID int,color varchar(20),begin_date date,end_date date,location varchar(20));
insert into @t values(1,'red','20170101','20170107','initial'),(1,'green','20170105','20170107','nursing'),(1,'blue','20170107','20170115','rehab'),(1,'red','20170111','20170122','Health'),(2,'red','20170222','20170226','initial'),(2,'green','20170226','20170228','nursing'),(2,'blue','20170226','20170228','rehab'),(3,'red','20170311','20170322','initial'),(4,'red','20170401','20170407','initial'),(4,'green','20170405','20170407','nursing'),(4,'blue','20170410','20170415','Health');

with d as
(
    select ID
        ,color
        ,begin_date
        ,end_date
        ,location
        ,row_number() over (partition by ID
                                        ,begin_date
                            order by case when location = 'initial' then '29990101' else begin_date end
                            ) as r
    from @t
)
select i.ID
        ,isnull(d.location,isnull(h.location,'Home')) as first_site
from d as i
    left join d
        on i.end_date = d.begin_date
            and d.r = 1
    left join d as h
        on i.ID = h.ID
            and h.location = 'Health'
where i.location = 'initial'
;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+
| ID | first_site |
+----+------------+
|  1 | rehab      |
|  2 | nursing    |
|  3 | Home       |
|  4 | Health     |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @example table (
    ExampleID   int identity(1,1) not null primary key clustered
,   ID          int not null
,   Color       nvarchar(255) not null
,   BeginDate   date not null
,   EndDate     date not null
,   Loc         nvarchar(255) not null
);

insert into @example (ID, color, begindate, enddate, loc)

select 1, 'red'   , '2017-01-01', '2017-01-07', 'initial' union all
select 1, 'green'  , '2017-01-05', '2017-01-07', 'nursing' union all
select 1, 'blue'  , '2017-01-07', '2017-01-15', 'rehab' union all
select 1, 'red'  , '2017-01-11', '2017-01-22', 'Health' union all
select 2, 'red'  , '2017-02-22', '2017-02-26', 'initial' union all
select 2, 'green'  , '2017-02-26', '2017-02-28', 'nursing' union all
select 2, 'blue'  , '2017-02-26', '2017-02-28', 'rehab' union all
select 3, 'red'  , '2017-03-11', '2017-03-22', 'initial' union all
select 4, 'red'  , '2017-04-01', '2017-04-07', 'initial' union all
select 4, 'green'  , '2017-04-05', '2017-04-07', 'nursing' union all
select 4, 'blue'  , '2017-04-10', '2017-04-15', 'Health';

    with cte as (
        select a.ID
             , a.Color
             , a.BeginDate
             , a.EndDate
             , b.Loc 
             , rank() over(partition by a.ID order by a.ID, a.begindate, b.enddate desc, b.loc) Ranking
          from @example a
     left join @example b
            on a.EndDate = b.BeginDate
                )
    , cte2 as (
        select id
             , Loc
          from @example
         where loc = 'health'
                )

    select a.ID
         , COALESCE(a.loc, b.loc, 'Home') as Loc 
      from cte a
 left join cte2 b
        on a.id = b.id
      where Ranking = 1
```

> Output:

```
ID  Loc
1   rehab
2   nursing
3   home
4   Health
```